# Crosswalk crashes with AssertionFailedError

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

Crashlytics reports the following problem, that is affecting a good percentage of the users of my application:

> Fatal Exception: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Cannot call
>   this method before xwalk is ready
>          at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
>          at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.setZOrderOnTop(XWalkView.java:1271)
>          at org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkWebViewEngine.initWebViewSettings(XWalkWebViewEngine.java:193)
>          at org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkWebViewEngine.access$000(XWalkWebViewEngine.java:55)
>          at org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkWebViewEngine$2.run(XWalkWebViewEngine.java:90)
>          at org.xwalk.core.XWalkActivityDelegate.onActivateCompleted(XWalkActivityDelegate.java:179)
>          at org.xwalk.core.XWalkLibraryLoader$ActivateTask.onPostExecute(XWalkLibraryLoader.java:314)
>          at org.xwalk.core.XWalkLibraryLoader$ActivateTask.onPostExecute(XWalkLibraryLoader.java:277)
>          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>          at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>          at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

I just added crosswalk as a plugin and I don't think I call any method explicitly (Cannot call this method before xwalk is ready). Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: having the same issue, and I'm curios of any solutions

Comment: @gion_13 Looking at the  XWalk code, this exception is thrown at any unsupported operation exceptions which is caused by calling methods in xwalk before it is ready. Did you had a look at this link - https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-4938 which specifies counter measures to avoid this

Comment: Experiencing this for the first time. Using ionic2 and fabric.io with xwalk. I'm not altering any native java code. hints were to post this bug(?) are appreciated.

Comment: @mjekov Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing something to the `XWalkView` while it's still in the not-ready state.

In the latest version of Crosswalk, there are some changes to the lib that the Crosswalk runtime isn't loaded yet when `onCreate()` is called. Therefore, if you want to initialize `XWalkView` or do something, wait until `XWalkActivity.onXWalkReady()` is called.

The solution is :

- Extend the activity containing `XWalkView` from `XWalkActivity`
- Override `XWalkActivity`'s `onXWalkReady()` methods, and do necessary initialization stuff to the `XWalkView` there

As already stated here: https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v5/org/xwalk/core/XWalkActivity.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not altering any java code. I'm just putting together some cordova plugins and I'm only coding javascript.